# VB.NET - Limit time an operation can take

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timeout

How can I limit the length of time an operation is allowed to take?

I have an external library that processes image files.  I'm running it against thousands of images, and every now and then the library gets stuck on certain images.  If I need to skip an image here or there, no problem, but I can't have the process get locked up, so I want to impose a maximum amount of time that the process is allowed to take for each image before I force it to give up and move on to the next image.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to run this code in a separate process.  Use Process.WaitForExit(int) to wait with a timeout and Process.Kill() when it returns false.

Comment: @Hans U should post that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the code in another thread, and then you would need to either run a timer (or another thread with a Threading.Thread.Sleep() method) and then after the specified amount of time is over, .Abort the thread.

Comment: Aborting a thread is evil - especially if it's executing an external library.